# Google Cloud Dataflow, BigQueryIO and NullPointerException on TableRow.get

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to GC Dataflow and didn't find a relevant answer here. Apologies if I should have found this already answered.

I'm trying to create a simple pipeline using the v2.0 SDK and am having trouble reading data into my PCollection using BigQueryIO. I am using the .withQuery method and I have tested the query in the BigQuery interface and it seems to be working fine. The initial PCollection seems to get created without any issues, but when I think setup a simple ParDo function to convert the values from the TableRow into a PCollection I am getting a NullPointerException on the line of code that does the .get on the TableRow object.

Here is my code. (I'm probably missing something simple. I'm a total newbie at Pipeline programming. Any input would be most appreciated.)

```
public class ClientAutocompletePipeline {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientAutocompletePipeline.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //  create the pipeline  
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(
                PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

        // A step to read in the product names from a BigQuery table
        p.apply(BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery("SELECT name FROM [beaming-team-169321:Products.raw_product_data]"))

        .apply("ExtractProductNames", ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                // Grab a row from the BigQuery Results
                TableRow row = c.element();

                // Get the value of the "name" column from the table row.
                //NOTE: This is the line that is giving me the NullPointerException 
                String productName = row.get("name").toString();

                // Make sure it isn't empty
                if (!productName.isEmpty()) {
                    c.output(productName);
                }
            }
        }))
```

The query definitely works in the BigQuery UI and the column called "name" is returned when I test the query. Why am I getting a NullPointerException on this line:

```
String productName = row.get("name").toString();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all of the values in the `name` column guaranteed not to be null?

Comment: If you run `SELECT name FROM [beaming-team-169321:Products.raw_product_data] where name is null` in BigQuery you'll see that there are null values. So, you need to take this into consideration in your pipeline.

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, that does make perfect sense. I guess I was under the incorrect impression that something was causing them all to be null because I had some error in my code, but I guess that might not have been the case. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when working with BigQuery and Dataflow (most likely the field is indeed `null`). If you are ok with using Scala, you could take a look at [Scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio) (which is a Scala DSL for Dataflow) and its [BigQuery IO](https://github.com/spotify/scio/wiki/Type-Safe-BigQuery).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! I don't have any experience with Scala, but I'll definitely check it out when I have some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just make your code `null` safe. Replace this:

`String productName = row.get("name").toString();`

With something like this:

`String productName = String.valueOf(row.get("name"));`

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm late for this but you can do something like `if(row.containsKey("column-name"))`.

This will basically tell you if the field is null or not.

In `BigQuery` what happens is, while reading data, if a column value is null, it is not available as a part of that particular `TableRow`. Hence, you are getting that error.

You can also do something like `if(null == row.get("column-name"))` to check if the field is null or not.